# Expo/ReactNativeElements/Storybook, extending theme issues

Tags: expo, storybook, react-native-elements

I am working on finding a way to create a ReactNativeElements UI library for our team, with Expo as our development environment (we use Expo on existing deployed apps), and using Storybook to create the library. I found [the official Expo "With Storybook" template](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-storybook) to start the project. One thing we want to do is utilize our company theme, which is a different format than the [`Colors`](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/customization/color) theme shape that ReactNativeElements has as default.

The `v4` [RNE docs](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/3.4.2/customization#typescript-definitions-extending-the-default-theme) suggest that you can extend the default theme, so I have been trying to follow this instruction.  One note is that the docs are not correct in v4, because creating the `react-native-elements.d.ts` is for v3, but now we need to create a `@rneui/themed` d.ts file.

The issue I run into is:

1. when creating my custom `ColorShape` and then inject to the `ThemeProvider`, the new shape is not accepted (unless I create the definition in the same file as initializing the ThemeProvider
2. the actual shape `myColorShape.text.primary` is not found

Step 1: create // @rneui.themed.d.ts.

```js
import "@rneui/themed";
import { ColorShape } from "../theme/colors/theme.type";

declare module "@rneui/themed" {
    export interface CreateThemeOptions {
       fluidColors: ColorShape;
    }
}
```

Step 2: initialize the ThemeProvider in `preview.ts` for Storybook to consume

```js
const withThemeProvider = (Story, context) => {
  const colors = useDarkMode() ? dark : light;

  const themeObj = createTheme({
    fluidColors: colors
  })
//  themeObj.fluidColors.backgroundColor is not found, `fluidColors` doesn't have any of the actual `ColorShape` as describe in the d.ts above??

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeObj}>
        {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

Note on step 2: if I **DO NOT** `declare module "@rneui/themed"` inside this preview file, TS error:

> Argument of type '{ fluidColors: ColorShape; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreateThemeOptions'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fluidColors' does not exist in type 'CreateThemeOptions'

This is really odd because I also have the d.ts file.

Step 3: Consume the theme in a simple component:

```js
import { Button as RNEButton, ButtonProps } from '@rneui/base';
import { ThemeContext, useTheme } from '@rneui/themed';
import { useContext } from 'react';

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
// theme.fluidColors does not exist
  const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);
// themeContext.theme does not contain the colors either

  return <RNEButton {...props} buttonStyle={{
    backgroundColor: '#19AFEB', // should be theme.fluidColors.backgroundColor
    borderRadius: 32,
  }}
  titleStyle={{
    color: '#FFF', // should be theme.fluidColors.text.primary
  }}
  />;
};
```

I have created a repo @: https://github.com/lucksp/expo-storybook

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

add `themed.d.ts` in root project (sibling of package.json) and custom theme like following.

```
// themed.d.ts
import "@rneui/themed";
import { TextStyle } from "react-native";

declare module "@rneui/themed" {
  export interface InputProps {
    required?: boolean;
    labelNumber?: number;
  }

  export interface TextProps {
    h5?: boolean;
    h5Style?: TextStyle;
    h6?: boolean;
    h6Style?: TextStyle;
    body?: boolean;
    bodyStyle?: TextStyle;
    caption?: boolean;
    CaptionStyle?: TextStyle;
    bold?: boolean;
    italic?: boolean;
    underline?: boolean;
    center?: boolean;
  }

  export interface ComponentTheme {
    Input: Partial<InputProps>;
    Text: Partial<TextProps>;
  }
}
```

I'm useing:

- Expo 49
- react native 0.72.5
- rneui 4.0.0-rc.8